# Deadbolt - Access failure redirect is not working

Tags: redirect, playframework-2.0, deadbolt

I am using Deadbolt 2 with Playframework 2.1

I have a public page from where the user clicks on a Action button and a Controller method is called, this method has @SubjectPresent on it. I want to redirect the user to the login page if the user is not logged in and then after the user logs in execute the method call.

I call the controller method through jsroutes as below

```
function launchDemo(demoId){

    jsRoutes.controllers.DemoLaunchApplication.launchDemo(demoId).ajax({

      success: function(data, textStatus) {
        $("#result").html(data);
      },
      error: function(data) {
      alert("error");
          $("#result").html(data);
      }

    }) 
  }
```

I have setup deadbolt 2 based on the project sample here.(https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/tree/master/samples/java/play-authenticate-usage)

I get the following errors in the console.

```
[error] application - Access to [/test/launch?testId=2] requires a subject, but no subject is present.
[warn] application - Deadbolt: Access failure on [/test/launch?testId=2]
```

and in the result div, the login page is being shown. I want to redirect to the login page instead and after login run the method call.

I did try to add statusCode and ajaxError, but the response header status was 200 and each time success block was executed which showed the login form in the result div.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to change the onAuthFailure of your DeadboltHandler implementation.  If you have copied the one from the example code, it's returning a 403.  Instead, you should return a redirect to your login page.

Comment: Steve, I have commented out forbidden and have set it to redirect - //return forbidden("Forbidden");
return redirect(PlayAuthenticate.getResolver().login());

Comment: Are you sure you haven't restricted access to your login page?

Comment: I have not restricted access to the login page. When I do normal get requests eg: http://localhost:9000/project the page gets redirected to http://localhost:9000/login.  In the above method, the ajax call results in a HTTP POST  http://localhost:9000/launch/demo?id=1 which internally gets redirected with HTTP status 303 and then the login page HTML content is returned as data.